# How to write using where and and conditions on active record rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

how to write this query using where and and conditions on active record rails

`SELECT c.name FROM`categories`as c join categories_coaches as cc on cc.category_id=c.id where cc.coach_id=16 and c.parent_id=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Category.joins(:categories_coaches)
    .where('categories_coaches.id = ? AND categories.parent_id = ?', 16, 1)
    .select('categories.name')
```

Comment: i tried it ... it is working thanks a lot :)  K M Rakibul Islam... thank you